# Conditional formatting based on the result of IF formula in the cell

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Is there a way we can do conditional formatting based on the result of IF condition present in cell no matter what it returns?

Like if it returns `true` then color it green if `false` color it red

The formula looks like this on sheet2 `=IF(Sheet3!C35="", Sheet3!B35, Sheet3!C35)` it can return any value which is in B or column C that's what makes it hard for me to conditionally format it using hardcoded values or ranges because they are not well defined

I thought of doing it via a macro like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Cells.HasFormula Then
            'Logic to check the if condition
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: evaluate the formula, which will give you the result, so if evaluate(target.formula)  or easier, have formula based CF, where C is checked, if <>"" then color, if not, do nothing

Comment: Why not just use the same formula in the Conditional Format? If you know a condition, just use that? So if your cell A1 has, for example, `=If(A2=B2,"True","False)`, then the conditoinal format for green would be `A2=B2`, and for red `A2<>B2`.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks I think that should do

Comment: You should probably first decide how your values will be formatted since you might have a wide range of different values. This seems like the issue you should be addressing first.

Comment: @LD16 No my issue is resolved I just wanted to check the result of the IF condtion if it returns true then give it a color else some other color which Nathan commented about how I can do that.

Comment: @BruceWayne I'd not use `True` in `""` because this will give error when excel is installed in other language than english, if you don't set the `""` it would take TRUE boolean and not true string

Comment: @Sgdva - Oh for sure, I was just writing a quick example. I'd use something like "Match" or "No Match" when really using it. I was trying to keep it simple to get the point across.

Comment: @sgdva - agree - I have tried it and it didn't do the formatting. not sure about the installation but i dont think he should worry about that. That does not happen often

Comment: @LD16 not that often, but, yeah, you should handle re usable codes in most situations, due to the fact it may help you later or to others :) I usually handle language/regional settings to the default by VBA so I take that out as a factor that may break the code.

Comment: @sgdva good stuff! definitely agree. can't go wrong with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you just place these conditional rules in the same cell as the if statement?

Formula for Green

```
=Sheet3!C35=""
```

Formula for Red

```
=Sheet3!C35<>""
```

Edit: Added picture showing formatting.

[image]

Comment: It's not just about one cell that's why and it would be a very time consuming task to change that condition in every cell

Comment: Set the apply to area to the entire column

Comment: No it's not that simple what if I autofill ? Then conditional formatting will check for cell C35 while formula for any other cell

Comment: See picture added to answer.

Comment: The conditional format will match the row if you don't use $ in the address.